# Thingsboard UI Customization

Tags: thingsboard

I would love to be able to customize the UI to fit the guidelines of our brand.
I'm not very familiar with Sass and Angular.
Can you suggest which IDE, tools or plugins are best in this particular project to modify and test the UI without having to build the whole project every time?

Thank you!

Comment: This is more of a research that should be done on Google. If your question is not specifically about a piece of code, error etc, then it is hard for people to write an answer and for sure the answer will be only one person's answer.

Answer (score 0):

thingsboard ui is using angularjs, react, webpack, babel and ... 
but all of the ui is connected to all project and i couldn't run it separate and after `npm install` and `npm run build` had some problems . based on pom.xml file in ui folder the project first is build with maven and make a jar file in ui folder then run it as front-end module . if we want not to clean install maven every time we change the project, one way is to run commands in pom.xml file ourselves . because the project does not use our global installed npm and node first it installs the particular version of them (nodeVersion: v6.9.1 npmVersion: 3.10.8) locally in ui folder then move them to folder named node and make link to node_modules : `ln -s node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js npm` after this run the commands:

```
node/npm install
node/npm run build
node/npm start
```

so you can write a script file to run all this commands together . don't forget to change your tb-gateway forwardHost and forwardPort in server.js file . the script file based on my os :

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ ! -d node-v6.9.1-linux-x64 ]  ; then
    wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.1/node-v6.9.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
    tar -xzvf node-v6.9.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
    mkdir node
    mv node-v6.9.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules node/
    mv node-v6.9.1-linux-x64/bin/* node/
    cd node
    ln -s node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js npm
    cd ..
fi
node/npm install
node/npm run build
node/npm start
```

after all this every ui project build will take time . you can use webstorm IDE or some web ides to open ui folder .

Comment: @fateme-fazil, every time i edit *package.json* under ui folder let say by adding 'gsap': '^2.0.2',  then import them in *widget.service.js' than run *mvn clean install -DskipTests*, deb is generated correctly but when running it, it show's this message 

  ```This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.```

now i go back and i remove all the change i made, generate the  deb again, the same error message still showing, do you have any idea what is happening,